# My IntelliSense is not displaying any autofill, even though the code still works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently installed Unity and Visual Studio Community. I'm still quite the beginner, but have a few months of practice on a different computer. The problem is my IntelliSense is not autofilling any of the words I know it used to fill on the other computer, which makes it really hard, especially for a beginner.

I've checked a bunch of articles, and following all their steps I know my IntelliSense settings are correct. It's just as if it doesn't know any of the C# terms. How do I solve this?

In the image below, I'm giving you an example of the fact that not even Vector3 autofills:

[Vector3 autofill not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsU3L.jpg)

Comment: Do you have `Visual Studio Tools For Unity` installed? Also how exactly are you opneing your script for editing? Do you doubleclick on it within Unity?

Comment: I do have Visual Studio Tools for Unity installed and I do open my scripts by double clicking on them in Unity yes

Comment: hm it doesn't even recognize `MonoBehaviour` or `Input` so apparently **anything** from the `UnityEngine` namespace though ...

Comment: Yes it is anything. So I'm not sure if there's a component that's just not installed or what but it is very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an optimal fix, but i would recommend this:

Open PlayerSettings in the Unity Inspector by selecting Edit > Project Settings > Player. Under the Configuration heading, click the Scripting Runtime Version dropdown and select . NET 4. x Equivalent.

Here's the [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Open%20PlayerSettings%20in%20the%20Unity,x%20Equivalent.) for more info

Hope this helps, as it did for me in the past when IntelliSense wasn't working in VS Code.